# VS2008 ignoring my membership tables, creating new aspnetdb.mdf instead

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, aspnetdb

I am making a web application in VS2008 for my final year project and I have a registration aspx form which uses a CreateUserWizard, which then creates / updates the various tables in the aspnetdb.mdf.

The problem is I want these aspnet tables in my own db I create, so as to link aspnet_Users.UserId to a new table. This led me to creating the new database in SSMS and running aspnet_regsql.exe to add membership tables to it which worked.

After creating my tables and relationships I then detached the db from SSMS and added it into the App_Data folder in my VS2008 web app project and changed my web.config connection string to reference this new database.

(This project will not be published - due to Uni lab restraints, the App_Data folder is my only option for storing a database)

However when I register any new users, a new aspnetdb.mdf is created rather than adding the new user to my attached db.

If anyone knows a reason for this and how I can fix it that would be great

Answer (score 0):

are you using personalization ? if so, the default provider uses the ASPNETDB by default.
change that and your done